# Wireless AP, I cannot ping host nor client

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, dns, hostapd, access-point

I'm setting up a wireless ap **without** internet connection. A client can connect to the **hostapd** server and obtain an ip address thanks to **dnsmasq**. The problem is that the client cannot ping the server and the server cannot ping the client. My server is a raspberry pi 3.

When pinging the client on the server host computer, I get `ping: connect: Network is unreachable`. Though the client is connected and has an ip address (tested with `$ ip a`).

I do not need internet access nor do I wanna set it up. I have therefor not set up a bridge.

This is my `hostapd.conf`:

```
# the interface used by the AP
interface=wlan0
# "g" simply means 2.4GHz band
hw_mode=g
# the channel to use
channel=10
# limit the frequencies used to those allowed in the country
ieee80211d=1
# the country code
country_code=SE
# 802.11n support
ieee80211n=1
# QoS support, also required for full speed on 802.11n/ac/ax
wmm_enabled=1

wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
ssid=raspi
wpa_passphrase=********
```

This is my `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=192.168.10.2,192.168.10.30,255.255.255.0,12h
dhcp-option=3,192.168.10.1
dhcp-option=6,192.168.10.1
server=8.8.8.8
log-queries
log-dhcp
listen-address=127.0.0.1
```

To start the ap I run:

```
wpa_cli terminate;
systemctl stop dhcpcd;
systemctl start hostapd;
systemctl start dnsmasq;
```

To stop the ap I run

```
systemctl stop dnsmasq;
systemctl stop hostapd;
systemctl restart dhcpcd;
```

I have tried to `nmap -sn 192.168.10.0/24` the network with only one result, the client, nmaping only the router at `192.168.10.1` gives nothing eventhough ssh is working on the pi (when ap is off and pi is connected to another wifi).

When doing `$ ip a` on the server it still has the same ip address as it had before starting the ap, when it was connected to the wifi, however, this ip address is not accessible via the *"old"* wifi.

**In conclusion**, it seems like the rpi can create an AP and give out IP addresses. It says it is connected with an ip address, but when pinging the rpi, it is not connected anywhere. The OS is freshly installed. How can I resolve this?

EDIT:

From server pov:

```
$ ping 192.168.10.10 # same for x.x.x.1 and x.x.x.0
ping: connect: Network is unreachable

$ ip route
# No output

$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:42:db:a0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:17:8e:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

From client pov:

```
$ ping 192.168.10.1 ## same output for x.x.x.0 too
ping 192.168.10.1
PING 192.168.10.1 (192.168.10.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.10.10 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.10.10 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.10.10 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.10.1 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 5054ms
pipe 3

$ ping 192.168.10.10 ## pinging the client itself
ping 192.168.10.10
PING 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.10.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.031 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.122 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.10: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.10: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
^C
--- 192.168.10.10 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3039ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.031/0.058/0.122/0.036 ms

$ ip route
default via 192.168.10.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp metric 302 
192.168.10.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.10.10 

$ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:61:9d:1b:3f:78 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.10/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Something was probably wrong in my last test as I said the server showed the old ip address it had, it does this every now and then when I restart the ap.

Comment: ip addr, ip route, ping command outputs

Comment: yes @gapsf as you requested above!

Comment: On server pov there is no ipv4 addresses configured on interfaces, obviously so ip wont work assign ip for wlan0 at least

Comment: Alright @gapsf makes sense, how can I configure that?

Comment: What os on pov is installed

Comment: @gapsf Debian bullseye for raspberry pi 3

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration

Comment: @gapsf I don't know if I get what you mean with "in addr add ip_addr dev wlan0", I'll look in the link you gave me, if you have an explanation and possibly an example as well I might flag your answer as correct.

Comment: ip addr add ip_addr dev wlan0 assigns address to wlan0

Comment: sorry @gapsf that doesn't make sense in my English, I cannot understand what you mean.

Comment: By this command you may assign ip address to wlan0 interface

Comment: Oh alright, thank you. It does add that ip address to the device `wlan0` but the server can still not ping the client and the client cannot ping the new ip address for the server

Comment: What ip addr shows now

Comment: @gapsf same, but with this added: `    inet 192.168.10.5/32 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
` and also the old ip address from before starting the ap, x.x.x.225 as I described above.

Comment: 192.168.10.5/24

Comment: @gapsf network is still unreachable for the server when pinging, when the client pings, it still hangs after sending the bytes as it would when pinging a non existing ip address

Comment: Routng table is empty.. Why you did not configure networking in pov as normal people do? Read how configure networking on debian and dont crush our brains https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration

Comment: @gapsf What do you mean by configure networking? What needs to be configured? I have set up a dns server and AP, what do I need to route? I don't plan to have internet so I don't get where I should route stuff.

Comment: If you think empty routing on OS is ok and without it all should work - good luck. https://opensource.com/business/16/8/introduction-linux-network-routing https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody encounters this in the future, running following commands after starting the AP and dhcp server did the job:

```
ifconfig wlan0 192.168.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.2.1
```

This is because I needed to setup an IP address for the wlan0 interface, and then route it to the network. That way the rpi is connected to the network since all of the network requests gets routed to the right address.